# Calling a function on a instance of my object returns a blank in console when ran

Tags: c++

Stuck on a homework program where i need to create a class Rectangle2D. I'm testing out my code but i can't get my getter functions to return their values .Here are the .cpp .h and main files. When i run my program, the console returns a blank. I'm trying to return my getter functions to return the value of the default constructor.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Rectangle2D.h"
using namespace std;


int main() {
    Rectangle2D rec1;
    rec1.getHeight();
    rec1.getWidth();
    rec1.getY();
    rec1.getX();
    return 0;
}



class Rectangle2D
{
private:
    double x;
    double y;
    double width;
    double height;

public:

    Rectangle2D();
    Rectangle2D(double x, double y, double width, double height);

    double getX();
    double getY();
    double getWidth();
    double getHeight();
    double getArea();
    double getPerimeter() const;
    bool contains(double, double)const;
};


#include "Rectangle2D.h"
#include <iostream>



Rectangle2D::Rectangle2D() {
    x = 0.0;
    y = 0.0;
    width = 1.0;
    height = 1.0;
}
Rectangle2D::Rectangle2D(double newX, double newY, double newWidth, double newHeight) {
    x = newX;
    y = newY;
    width = newWidth;
    height = newHeight;
}

double Rectangle2D::getX() {
    return x;
}
double Rectangle2D::getY() {
    return y;
}
double Rectangle2D::getWidth() {
    return width;
}
double Rectangle2D::getHeight() {
    return height;
}

double Rectangle2D::getArea() {
    return width * height;
}
double Rectangle2D::getPerimeter()const {
    return (2 * width) + (2 * height);
}
bool Rectangle2D::contains(double findX, double findY) const {
    return (1 == 1);
}
```

Comment: The blank output might be solved by actually having some print statements that print the return values

Comment: To get some output to the console you might want to to use `cout << rec1.getHeight();`, etc.

Comment: Your `main` does the same thing as `int main() { 1.0; 1.0; 0.0; 0.0; }`

Comment: The get functions return a variable, as it happens is a `double` here. You need to do something with this. One option is to use `std:;cout` to print it to a console. Or store it in a variable for later use. Since this is a learning exercsie, conside why you have `const` on some functions and not others. You can (and should) make all your getter `const`. They don't change the `Rectangle`.

Answer (score 1):

Write output, you just call methods without printing them to console:

```
int main() {
    Rectangle2D rec1;
    std::cout << "Height - " << rec1.getHeight() <<std::endl;
    std::cout << "width - " << rec1.getWidth() <<std::endl;
    std::cout << "Y - " << rec1.getY() <<std::endl;
    std::cout << "X - " << rec1.getX() <<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!!

Comment: @jerryy , Good Luck!